# How C# compareto method compares Strings

Tags: c#, compareto

I want to know how CompareTo method of C# compares two strings, so I tested like this :

```
string str1 = "0";
string str2 = "-";
Console.WriteLine(str1.CompareTo(str2)); // output : 1
string str3 = "01";
string str4 = "-1";
Console.WriteLine(str3.CompareTo(str4)); // output : -1
```

Why the results are different?

Comment: It uses `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare`, so it's the Culture settings that determine the sort order, but the results do look very strange.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TLDR**: The default lexicographical string ordering treats `-` characters specially.

The answer to this is that the default string comparison uses lexicographical sorting rules.

This means that some symbols - for example, `-`, are treated specially.

[The documentation for CompareOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.compareoptions(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> The .NET Framework uses three distinct ways of sorting: word sort,
>   string sort, and ordinal sort. Word sort performs a culture-sensitive
>   comparison of strings. Certain nonalphanumeric characters might have
>   special weights assigned to them. For example, the hyphen ("-") might
>   have a very small weight assigned to it so that "coop" and "co-op"
>   appear next to each other in a sorted list. String sort is similar to
>   word sort, except that there are no special cases. Therefore, all
>   nonalphanumeric symbols come before all alphanumeric characters.
>   Ordinal sort compares strings based on the Unicode values of each
>   element of the string.

In your case, the default ordering is being used: Word sort.

You can see the different results by specifying the kind of comparison you want in `string.Compare()`:

```
string str3 = "01";
string str4 = "-1";
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(string.Compare(str3, str4, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))); // output : -1
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(string.Compare(str3, str4, StringComparison.Ordinal)));          // output : 1
```

Here you can see that it is treating the `-` specially when not doing an Ordinal comparison.

It really is the `-` that's being treated specially - it's not assuming it's a minus sign. For example, if you use `+` instead of `-` you get:

```
string str1 = "0";
string str2 = "+";
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))); // output : 1
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.Ordinal)));          // output : 1
string str3 = "01";
string str4 = "+1";
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(string.Compare(str3, str4, StringComparison.InvariantCulture))); // output : 1
Console.WriteLine(Math.Sign(string.Compare(str3, str4, StringComparison.Ordinal)));          // output : 1
```

---

**ASIDE**

Do not confuse a normal hyphen with a soft hyphen!

- A normal hyphen has the Unicode value `\u002D`.
- A soft hyphen has the Unicode value `\u00AD`.

Note [the documentation for `string.Compare()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx) which has sample code that shows a *soft* hyphen being ignored. The documentation states:

> Character sets include ignorable characters. The
>   Compare(String, String, Boolean) method does not consider such
>   characters when it performs a culture-sensitive comparison.

A *soft* hyphen is one of the ignorable characters, but it is important to note that a soft hyphen is NOT THE SAME AS a normal hyphen. So this documentation DOES NOT APPLY to your sample code.

The actual reason for the *normal* hyphen behaving differently is given above.

(If you want a complete list of all ignorable characters in Unicode, go to http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/DerivedCoreProperties.txt and search for `Default_Ignorable_Code_Point` - and note that this list does not in fact include the normal hyphen.)